# Need equal height columns to resize with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script for equal height columns. I just ran into a problem where the table-filter/sort/paginate plugin can change the height of my inner window beyond the initial document load. Im not really sure how to use resize() correctly someone up for walking me through this?

```
/*******************************/
/*  EQUAL HEIGHT COLUMNS
/*******************************/
$(window).load(function() {
   var maxHeight = -1;

   $('.equal').each(function() {
     maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
   });

   $('.equal').each(function() {
     $(this).height(maxHeight);
   });
 });
```

EDIT:

I tried to bind the resize and load like this, but did not work...

```
/*******************************/
/*  EQUAL HEIGHT COLUMNS
/*******************************/
$(window).on("resize", function() {
   var maxHeight = -1;

   $('.equal').each(function() {
     maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
   });

   $('.equal').each(function() {
     $(this).height(maxHeight);
   });
 });.resize();
```

Comment: it sounds to me like your problem is that you are setting column heights ONCE on page load, the jquery plugin is then changing them. you should call your method after each filter event

Comment: also, $(window) is not resizeing, $('.equal') is resizing. you should apply the event to `.equal`

Comment: $('.equal').each.on("resize", function() {...};.resize(); ??? Sorry, I'm still learning my javascript syntax

Comment: updated my answer to contain full script

Comment: did you figure this one out? does your method work without the jquery plugin? try puttin a console.log() within the "resize" event, does it get hit?

Comment: no its not working yet, i put the resize event in console a while back  and no hits when the box expanded. the deal is that the first script i posted in my OP works provided there is no dynamic content on the page, but things like tabbed divs and the filter plugin break things in a hurry.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47210/discussion-between-eru-and-ten-design)

Comment: Just joined chat, but i was away for a while. Anyhow, I installed the plugin, and used the script you worked up below, still not working. More specifically, nothing is being sized.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code to:

```
$('window .equal').on('resize', function() {
     var maxHeight = -1;

     $('.equal').each(function() {
         maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
         $(this).height(maxHeight);
     });
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct felix. the first col will be resized to its own height regardless of the others

Comment: @Eru I'm not sure but still fixed, Thanks :)

Comment: Yea, I think the key was `'window .equal'` instead of just 'window'. there is still a logic error though, try your method body inside this skeleton

Comment: @TENDesign Try to use Eru's suggestion

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I lied, you need the [jquery resize plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/) for this to work!

```
<script src="http://github.com/cowboy/jquery-resize/raw/v1.1/jquery.ba-resize.js"></script>
```

Window is not resizing, it is the `.equal` columns that resize. attatch to their resize event.

```
$('.equal').on("resize",  function(){
  var maxHeight = -1;

  $('.equal').each(function() {
     maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
  });

  $('.equal').each(function() {
     $(this).height(maxHeight);
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
#wrapper{overflow:hidden;}
#div1{width:200px;background: red;float: left;padding-bottom:10000px;margin-bottom:-10000px;}
#div2{width:300px;background: blue;float: left;padding-bottom:10000px;margin-bottom:-10000px;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1">
        a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>
    </div>
</div>
```

You don't need any javascript, if you think your page could have more than 10000px hieght than just increase the padding-bottom and margin-bottom in negative and maintain in same amount.